# How to determine the likelihood function for $Y_i=u+(1+\phi*x_i)e_i$, $e_i \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

The way I see it there's two way to define my Likelihood function:
$L(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n;u,\phi)=Y_1*Y_2*...*Y_n$

or

$L(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n;u,\phi)=f(Y_1)*f(Y_2)*...*f(Y_n)$, where $f(Y_i)=N(u,(1+\phi*x_i)^2*1)$

Are any of those the right to determine the likelihood function?

Comment: Please tell us what "$f$" refers to.  Your notation has to be interpreted in a very specific way for your second formula to even make sense, and it has to be interpreted even more narrowly for it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is right.

Not sure where you got the idea that the first one might be from, since it doesn't depend on the parameters at all while the densities clearly do...